# RGBA image saves as blank in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I'm running a Jupyter notebook with the following code:

```
#rgba
img = np.zeros((large_img_width, large_img_height, 4), dtype = "uint8")

#generate image_list_1 here

for k,image in enumerate(image_list_1):
    #more image operations here
    img[src_img_pos[0]:src_img_pos[0] + tilesize,src_img_pos[1]:src_img_pos[1] + tilesize] = dst_tile

cv2.imshow('Large img', img)

pillarge = Image.fromarray(img,'RGBA')
pillarge.save("collages/" + time_str + "_large.png", "PNG")


# allows us to see image
# until closed forcefully
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I use cv2.imshow I see the result, but when I try to save the image with PIL, I get a blank PNG file, that always seems to be > 1 MB in filesize, so it's not empty.

Running PIL v '8.2.0' in Anaconda on Ubuntu Linux 20.04

What could be the problem here?